# Metodos privados en clases Javascript

Tags: javascript

mi pregunta es como definir metodos privados en clases javascript para que no puedan ser accedidos directamente.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, password, email) {
  this.name     = name;
  this.password = password;
  this.email    = email;
  }

  privado(){
   console.log("Accediste a un metodo privado")
  }
}

var u = new User("usuario","123","usuario@example.com");
u.privado();
```

Intente definiendo variables por fuera del constructor pero no funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba esto,

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, password, email) {
  this.name     = name;
  this.password = password;
  this.email    = email;
        var privado_ = function(){
          console.log('realmente esto es privado');
        };
    
       this.privado = function(){
         console.log("Accediste a un metodo privado");
          privado_();
       }
  }

}

var u = new User("usuario","123","usuario@example.com");
u.privado();
```

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript no implementa la programación orientada a objetos igual que lenguajes como Java, C#, etc. En JavaScript, básicamente no existe el concepto de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)). Aun así, debido a su gran flexibilidad puedes simularlo con algo de ingenio.

---

**Referenciando variables/funciones**

Es lo más sencillo y más práctico. Creas las funciones o variables **fuera de la clase** y las referencias dentro de la clase.

```js
class User {
 publico () {
   console.log('Soy un método público');
    privado(); // se ejecuta correctamente
  }
}

let pepito = new User();
pepito.publico();
pepito.privado(); // pepito.privado is not a function

function privado () {
    console.log('Soy un método privado');
}
```

**Usando Factorías**

> Recuerda: en Javascript **no existe** el concepto de *clases*. Aún en ES6 y la llegada de la palabra reservada `class` sigue sin existir como tal. JavaScript es un lenguaje **prototipado**. Aunque uses la nueva sintaxis para crear *"clases"*, estarás creando **funciones** con un prototipo.

Esta forma es la que se acostumbra a usar cuando se quiere implementar variables o métodos privados. El truco está en devolver un objeto que **haga referencia** a variables y/o métodos propios y *locales* de la función en el objeto a devolver. Esta es la magia de los [`closures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
function User () {
  const privado = function () {
    console.log('Soy un método privado');
  }
  
  return {
    publico () {
      console.log('Soy un método público');
      privado(); // se ejecuta correctamente
    }
  }
}

let pepito = User();
pepito.publico();
pepito.privado(); // pepito.privado is not a function
```

Answer (score 5):

Aunque la respuesta de @jolsalazar me gustó y me pareció bastante práctica, quiero dejar el modo en que yo resolví esto y que a mi parecer me parece un poco más 'elegante':

```js
var Salute = (function (){

    // Esta función es nuestro constructor
    function Salute(lang){
        this._lang = lang;
    }

    // Este es nuestro método privado
    function Hi(){
        if(this._lang == "en"){
            alert('Hi, I am a private method');
        }else if(this._lang == "es"){
            alert('Hola, Yo soy un método privado');
        }
    }

    // Este es nuestro método público
    Salute.prototype.sayHi = function () {
        return Hi.call(this);
    }

    return Salute;

})();

var salute_es = new Salute('es');

salute_es.Hi(); 
// La consola nos mostrará que Hi(); 
// no es una función válida

salute_es.sayHi();  
// Nos saldrá un alert con el texto 
// 'Hola, Yo soy un método privado'
```

Explico un poco mi código:

Creamos un '*objeto*' con una **función auto invocada** (en inglés *self invoking function*) y usamos el método `prototype` para 'inyectar' una nueva función y hacerla 'pública' mediante la función [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/call) pasandole el contexto `this` como argumento.

Cabe aclarar que en `javascript` no hay palabras reservadas tales como `public` o `private` para definir métodos dentro de una `Class` y por esto se debe realizar un tipo de 'hack' como el anterior mostrado.

Comment: Esto vuelve a ser `ES5`, y pienso que la idea de la pregunta, es encontrar una manera en la que se pueda usar la nueva sintaxis.

Answer (score 5):

Si bien JavaScript no es un lenguaje Orientado a Objetos podemos acercarnos teniendo en cuenta la definición de un método privado.

> Los métodos privados son aquellos métodos que se pueden llamar desde métodos de la clase, pero nunca de forma externa a la clase.

Lo primero que se debe hacer es omitir la palabra reservada this en el constructor.

Definimos el método privado();  y un metodo publico llamado method(); el cual invoca a los métodos privados y este sera el que podemos llamar desde métodos javascript externos.

De esta forma recuerda que las variables y métodos con this son publicas y con var privadas.

```js
class User {
 
 constructor(name, password, email) {
  var name     = name;
  var password = password;
  var email    = email;
        var privado  = function() { 
          console.log("Accediste a un metodo privado"); 
        }
        
        this.getPrivado = function(){ privado(); }
  }
  
}

var u = new User("usuario","123","usuario@example.com");
u.getPrivado();
```

Answer (score 2):

Algo que funciona muy bien es implementar miembros de clase con # por delante

```
export class Ceil
{
    // miembros privados
    #intm = 0;
    #intn = 0;
    #inta = 0;

    constructor (intm, intn, inta)
    {
        this.#intm = intm;
        this.#intn = intn;
        this.#inta = inta;
    }

    // metodo publico
    printNumCeil = () =>
    {
        var intHorCeil;
        var intVertCeil;

        intHorCeil = this.#getNumCeil(this.#intm, this.#inta);
        intVertCeil = this.#getNumCeil(this.#intn, this.#inta);

        console.log(intHorCeil * intVertCeil);
    };

    // metodo privado
    #getNumCeil = (intDimCeil, intDimArea) =>
    {
        return (intDimArea + intDimCeil - 1) / intDimArea;
    }; 
}
```